# Vue Reactivity not triggering when reloading the page due to async mismatch?

Tags: typescript, async-await, vuejs3

I'm building a simple SPA using the options API, with the simplest state management possible: just exporting a Ref from a store.ts file. This Ref is filled onBeforeMount by making a fetch request to an API. I have a child route with an edit form that gets prefilled with the data fetched from the api. So far so good, the data gets loaded as expected, however if I reload the page the model binding wont update the view, and the form fields will be empty.

I've checked on the Vue DevTools and I can see that my state Ref is being correctly set up after the reload, so I'm assuming that this is some mismatch between when my async function resolves and the reactivity api. I tried using nextTick in different places but it didn't work.

See part of the code bellow:

**router/index.ts**

```ts
routes: [
    {
        path: "/users/:id",
        name: "users_view",
        component: UserView,
        props: true,
        children: [
            {
                path: "edit",
                name: "edit_user",
                component: UserForm,
                props: true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**store.ts**

```ts
export const current_user: Ref<User | undefined> = ref(undefined);
```

**views/UserView.vue**

```vue
<script setup lang="ts">
// ...I'm ommiting the other imports here, not relevant
import { current_user } from "@/store";

type Props = {
    id: string;
};

const props = defineProps<Props>();

onBeforeMount(() => {
    // Fetching user from the api
    new CaseResource().find(props.id).then(user => {
        current_user.value = user
    })
});
</script>

<template>
    <RouterView />
</template>
```

**views/UserForm.vue**

```vue
<script setup lang="ts">
// ...I'm ommiting the other imports here, not relevant
import { current_user } from "@/store";

const model = ref({});

onBeforeMount(() => {
   if (current_user) {
       model.value = { ...current_user.value };
   }
});
</script>

<template>
    <form>
        <input ... v-model="model.foo">
        <input ... v-model="model.bar">
        ...
    </form>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly a side effect, should have watched for changes, [watchEffect](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watcheffect) did it.